# How to automatically remove restricted access of an Excel file with Python in order to read it into Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, excel, permissions

I have a large set of Excel files with restricted access I've put on it.
The goal is to remove the restriction automatically for all Excel files in a folder, so that I can read them into my Python script and work with them normally. Currently, this is not possible and I get the error message "Can't find workbook in OLE2 compound document".
In the attached picture, you see what I mean without Python.
[What I want to automate in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz4BC.png)

Is there a way to do so?

I've searched many web pages and forums on this topic and mostly found ways to remove password-restrictions or other not suitable methods.
Especially for the error message "Can't find workbook in OLE2 compound document", there were only solutions regarding how to remove password restriction.

Other approaches like converting the Excels into a Zip did either not work at all or succeeded first and then I had a completely different structure in the 7Zip-viewer then in the guidelines (every code was encrypted) telling how to remove a certain chunk to enable access.

I would appreciate any help! Thanks